# Password checkbox field AngularJS min/maxlength issue

Tags: forms, angularjs

I made a password field that shows the password when checking a checkbox.
I'm using ng-minlenght and ng-maxlength to control the password length.

When the password is between the min and max length of the input field it shows the password text as it should.

But when the password is not valid/ not between min and max length of the field I get an emtpy value.

[Plnkr Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6ezLdIekzjLMY6tBEq8?p=preview)

Is this a bug in Angular or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, but I can't find any reference in the docs that states it explicitly.  Angular is not changing your model until the validation criteria are met.  You can see that demonstrated by adding `{{user.password}}` above your inputs ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZVTd989MGq1ldSDI7zw?p=preview)).  You won't see the text on the page until you type 8 characters.

You can get around this by using a directive that manually syncs up the two text fields like so:

**http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/K6Qgm/11/**

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="x">
    password is: {{user.password}}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    standard input:
    <input ng-model="user.password" name="uPassword" type="password" ng-hide="isChecked" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    password directive: 
    <password ng-model="user.password" name="uPassword" />
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function x($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        password: 'x'
    };
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('password', function () {
    return {
        template: '' +
            '<div>' +
            '    <input type="text" ng-model="ngModel" name="name" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" required />' +
            '    <input type="password" ng-model="ngModel" name="name" ng-minlength="ngMinlength" required />' +
            '    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="viewPasswordCheckbox" />' +
            '</div>',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            name: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('viewPasswordCheckbox', function (newValue) {
                var show = newValue ? 1 : 0,
                    hide = newValue ? 0 : 1,
                    inputs = element.find('input');
                inputs[show].value = inputs[hide].value;
                inputs[hide].style.display = 'none';
                inputs[show].style.display = '';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and the response ;) will try this out

Comment: I'm actually still playing around with it -- I can't seem to get form validation working inside of the directive. It doesn't seem to play well with the form.

Comment: It's weird that he doesn't hold the value in his scope, I think I'll remove the ng-minlength and controle the values myself